# Small Issues with powershell Script that loops over folders in Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

This Script loops over every folder in powershell and checks if the folder has the wildcard text and then outputs the file location towards the csv.

The error i get is : Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

Also some of the folders containing the wildcard. Mostly in level 3 - 4 - 5 it does not detect even tough in the output i see a folder containing the word.
Thanks in advance !

```
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell

#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "*******/sites/Archief"
$Folder = "Gedeelde Documenten"
$Pagesize = "500"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive ### Change to your specific site ###

#Output path
$outputPath = "C:\users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\test.csv"



Function GetFolders($folderUrl)  
{      
    $folderColl=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderUrl -ItemType Folder   
    # Loop through the folders  
    foreach($folder in $folderColl)  
    {                      
       $newFolderURL= $folderUrl+"/"+$folder.Name
       if ($newFolderURL -cnotlike "*archief*"){
           write-host -ForegroundColor Green $folder.Name " - " $newFolderURL
           $DocLibs = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseTemplate -eq 101} 
            #Loop thru each document library & folders
            $results = @()
            foreach ($DocLib in $DocLibs) {
                if ($DocLib -cnotlike "*archief*"){
                    $AllItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $DocLib -Fields "FileRef", "File_x0020_Type", "FileLeafRef" -PageSize 500
                    #Loop through each item
                    foreach ($Item in $AllItems) {
                        if ($Item["FileRef"] -cnotlike "*archief*" -or $Item["FileLeafRef"] -cnotlike "*archief*" -and ($Item["File_x0020_Type"])){
                            Write-Host "File found. Path:" $Item["FileRef"] -ForegroundColor Green               
                            #Creating new object to export in .csv file
                            $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                Path          = $Item["FileRef"]
                                FileName      = $Item["FileLeafRef"]
                                FileExtension = $Item["File_x0020_Type"]
                           }
                    }
                 }
            }
    }
           GetFolders($newFolderURL)
        }
    }           
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation

GetFolders($folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all, you first output the results to a CSV and after that call the function. Also you loop through the folders, and constantly create a new results object which is never outputted. lastly you call the function itself from within the function. You call GetFolders in a foreach loop within the GetFolders function.

There are a few ways to resolve this, for instance let the CSV be filled from inside the function and append new data.

```
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell

#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "*******/sites/Archief"
$Folder = "Gedeelde Documenten"
$Pagesize = "500"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive ### Change to your specific site ###

#Output path
$outputPath = "C:\users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\test.csv"


Function GetFolders{      
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $FolderUrl,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $OutputPath
    )
    
    $folderColl=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderUrl -ItemType Folder   
    # Loop through the folders  
    foreach($folder in $folderColl){                      
        $newFolderURL= $folderUrl+"/"+$folder.Name
        if ($newFolderURL -cnotlike "*archief*"){
            write-host -ForegroundColor Green $folder.Name " - " $newFolderURL
            $DocLibs = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseTemplate -eq 101} 
            #Loop thru each document library & folders
            $results = @()
            foreach($DocLib in $DocLibs){
                if($DocLib -cnotlike "*archief*"){
                    $AllItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $DocLib -Fields "FileRef", "File_x0020_Type", "FileLeafRef" -PageSize 500
                    #Loop through each item
                    foreach ($Item in $AllItems) {
                        if ($Item["FileRef"] -cnotlike "*archief*" -or $Item["FileLeafRef"] -cnotlike "*archief*" -and ($Item["File_x0020_Type"])){
                            Write-Host "File found. Path:" $Item["FileRef"] -ForegroundColor Green               
                            #Creating new object to export in .csv file
                            $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                Path          = $Item["FileRef"]
                                FileName      = $Item["FileLeafRef"]
                                FileExtension = $Item["File_x0020_Type"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $results | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation -Append
            GetFolders($newFolderURL)
        }
    }            
}

GetFolders -FolderUrl $Folder -OutputPath $outputPath
```

As you can see the output path is added to the function and the results are pushed to the CSV after every loop.

You could also let the results be created within the function and then returned to the initial call:

```
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell

#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "*******/sites/Archief"
$Folder = "Gedeelde Documenten"
$Pagesize = "500"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive ### Change to your specific site ###

#Output path
$outputPath = "C:\users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\test.csv"


Function GetFolders{      
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $FolderUrl
    )
    
    $folderColl=Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderUrl -ItemType Folder   
    # Loop through the folders 
    $results = @()
    foreach($folder in $folderColl){                      
        $newFolderURL= $folderUrl+"/"+$folder.Name
        if ($newFolderURL -cnotlike "*archief*"){
            write-host -ForegroundColor Green $folder.Name " - " $newFolderURL
            $DocLibs = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseTemplate -eq 101} 
            #Loop thru each document library & folders
            foreach($DocLib in $DocLibs){
                if($DocLib -cnotlike "*archief*"){
                    $AllItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $DocLib -Fields "FileRef", "File_x0020_Type", "FileLeafRef" -PageSize 500
                    #Loop through each item
                    foreach ($Item in $AllItems) {
                        if ($Item["FileRef"] -cnotlike "*archief*" -or $Item["FileLeafRef"] -cnotlike "*archief*" -and ($Item["File_x0020_Type"])){
                            Write-Host "File found. Path:" $Item["FileRef"] -ForegroundColor Green               
                            #Creating new object to export in .csv file
                            $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                Path          = $Item["FileRef"]
                                FileName      = $Item["FileLeafRef"]
                                FileExtension = $Item["File_x0020_Type"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            GetFolders($newFolderURL)
        }
    }
    return $results            
}

GetFolders -FolderUrl $Folder | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

I would also recommend using '-Delimiter ";"' in your Export-CSV so that when you open the file in Excel it is automatically sorted.

Comment: Thanks ! This works. How come i get the problems with the wildcard when going thru the folders ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: well actually none. but for example: it loops through every folder in the sharepoint. and if 1 folder is containing the word "archief" in upper or lowecase. it may not go into that folder or not list it. the eventual purpose is that we delete everything that is not in a folder called "archief"

Comment: You should really look through your script because it still does not make much sense to be honest. You loop through the folders, but don't actually do anything but output the name with it. Then foreach folder you obtain the list with all docLibs and query the same items over and over again... Just start small outside the function and create the logic step by step would be my advise!